# Step up DC voltage from 12-24V to 60V

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I need to provide a 60V/1A power source from a 12-24V input, -40 to 85 degC temperature range. Parametric searches for DC/DC converters at a couple online vendors don't seem to be turning up much.

I'd prefer a simple chassis mount module of some kind, really.

Are there (readily available) DC/DC converters out there that satify these criteria? If not, how can I go about designing something that will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nat Semi Simple Switcher? Try the on-line design software [here](http://www.national.com/analog/power/simple_switcher).

Comment: I ended up going with National's LM5118...  the web designer is a very nice tool.

Comment: Try not to use electrolytic capacitors (they tend to dramatically lose capacitance at -40C) and make sure that you have ample cooling for the device - the MOSFET drivers inside the IC will dissipate power and it won't take much for the IC to reach OTP at 85C ambient. You could consider having high input-Z drivers outside the IC, moving the power from inside the package to outside of it. Make sure you have an external over-voltage protection circuit too, for safety.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind building the SMPS yourself, [here](http://tinyurl.com/69cnrm3) is a list of Linear Technology devices that match your criteria.

Comment: Huh...  I just tried that and didn't get any hits. I must have messed up the topology and didn't notice.

Comment: Ah... I came in from a single small category, got distracted, then forgot that little detail when I came back to it. LTC3862 looks good to me. Thanks!